# Why does an entity escape at the end of the string not show up for document.write(x) on domready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document.write, html-escape-characters

```js
var target = '<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"upfiles\/54591303758197437.jpg\" \/><\/p>'
$(function(){
    var x=$('<div/>').text(target).html();
    alert(x);
    document.write(x)
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I show the escaped string contained html tags and write in webpage.
The escaped string in the alert window is right, but after closing the alert window you can ony see ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVIhM.png)):

```
<p><img alt="" src="upfiles/54591303758197437.jpg" /></p
```

Where is the last `>` ?

Why `<p><img alt="" src="upfiles/54591303758197437.jpg" /></p>` won't show up in the webpage?

Comment: Why are you even using `document.write` in the first place? Even without jQuery there are far better methods of doing without what you want.

Comment: Guys, lets give the OP some benefit of doubt. For example, this *does* work for me in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari. I am seeing the same error as the above in Safari on macOS.

Comment: @Xufox it's odd it works for you as I get the same result as the OP in Chrome 68: https://i.imgur.com/algJh0W.png

Comment: makes no sense why / is escaped.

Comment: It works fine in Firefox Nightly 64.0a1.

Comment: @epascarello Maybe not, but that doesn't invalidate the result either.

Comment: So simplify it to `document.write("&gt;")` and see what happens. Betting it still happens.

Comment: @epascarello I removed all the escaping, and changed the string to `'<p><img alt="" src="upfiles/54591303758197437.jpg"/></p>'`, it still breaks for me in Safari. Though adding an extra space at the end fixes it. :confused:

Comment: @epascarello `document.write("&gt;")` doesn't print anything, as you assumed! But, `document.write("&gt; ")` does. Haunted Safari?

Comment: Adding anything to the end fixes it. My last comment showed it happens with just that escape sequence by itself. Why? no clue, why. Why not wrap it in a span or paragraph tag?

Comment: So, I was able to reproduce this in a different browser. This only happens when `document.write` is used _after_ the DOM is loaded (which is very bad anyway). The minimal example is `addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => document.write("&gt;"))` which prints nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same symptom on Chrome 69 (Windows).

Managed to fix it by adding a `document.close()` call, as recommended by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write):

```js
target = '<p><img alt=\"\" src=\"upfiles\/54591303758197437.jpg\" \/><\/p>'
$(function(){
    x=$('<div/>').text(target).html();
    alert(x);
    document.write(x);
    document.close();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Bravo! Do as the documentation says. Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

The correct and officially documented answer to this perplexing conundrum is in [@PeterB's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52276292/2206733). For anyone looking for a quick fix, just append a space at the end of string, and you're back to sanity.

```
document.write(x+' ')
```